# Javascript - How to change the value of a Select before form submit

Tags: javascript

```js
var fruit = $("[name=fruit] option").detach()
$("[name=color]").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val()
  $("[name=fruit] option").detach()
  fruit.filter("." + val).clone().appendTo("[name=fruit]")
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=color>
<option>Select a color</option>
<option>green</option>
<option>red</option>
<option value="dark_red">dark red</option>
<option>yellow</option>
</select>
<select name=fruit>
<option class=green>Grapes</option>
<option class=green>Watermelon</option>
<option class="red green">Apples</option>
<option class="dark_red red">Cherries</option>
<option class="green yellow">Bananas</option>
<option class=yellow>Lemons</option>
```

I have two selects. When I select one option from the first select, the second select it's updated with a list of available options.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/u9gfro3h/20/)

The problem is that when a color is made up of more than one word, for example: dark red

The `value` of the `dark red` option is set to `value="dark_red"`.

In my backend my model expects the value of each option to be the original value (without `'_'`)

Is there any possibility to change the value of the selected option before the form submit and remove the `'_'`?

So when the user is manipulating the selects the value would be `dark_red` but when the user submits the form, in the `request.POST` the value would be `dark red`.

or alternatively (even better) is it possible to make the code work using another attribute such as:

`id="dark_red"` and don't edit the value attribute?

UPDATE: Snippet added

Comment: Is it not possible to change the select values to those expected by the back end? Also, are you using jQuery to submit the form, or what?

Comment: please add a snippet of your code. jsFiddle doesn't work on my connection

Comment: @MisterJojo Added :) thank you!

Comment: Would you tell me, how to submit the selection to the server?

Comment: @MattU It's a regular html from that I process on the backend, but I should probably modify the form via jQuery before it's submitted.

Comment: @MattU yeah something like that would be my last option but it sure would work. Wouldn't it be possible to filter by another attribute modifying the code that I have attached? Instead of checking option value checking option id, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replace` function to replace `_` with   empty space

```js
let myString = "grapes_green";
let myNewString = myString.replace("_", " ");

console.log(myString);
console.log(myNewString);
```

And send the `myNewString` to the Server

Read More About `replace` function at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)